# How to save multiple user details in user defaults?

Tags: ios, swift

I got a task to store multiple user details.

```
@IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var email_id: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
```

I know in user defaults we can store a value for a particular key and retrieve it but i would like to know how to save multiple values. like the key should be the email_id i have mentioned above and all the three fields should be its values, also i need to maintain all the details even if there is n number of users.

Comment: What did you try for saving values? Have your worked on Dictionary, Sets etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save textField Data in dictionary as a key-value and append that dictionary to Array.So you will get the list of users detail.It will not override, every time it make empty dictionary after click on save Button and before append the data.

like that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var userDict = [String:Any]()
var userArray = [Any]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
```

and save the data after save button click.

```
@IBAction func SaveBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        userDict = [:]
        userDict.updateValue(userName.text, forKey: "username")
        userDict.updateValue(email_id.text, forKey: "email")
        userDict.updateValue(password.text, forKey: "password")

        userArray.append(userDict)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it in this situation is to use a local database, like sqlite. You can follow [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift) tutorial for dealing with a local database. In your situation, you will need a user table to store your users.

If you prefer not to use a local database and use UserDefault instead, you can indeed store an array of objects in UserDefault. Simply use the following code

```
UserDefaults.standard.set([YourUserObj], forKey: "users")

let userArr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "users") as? [YourUserObj]
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You can store multiple values using tuples.

> Rule:  A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance
>   of (or for collections, a combination of instances of): NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary

If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

```
// you can create NSObject model to store into userdefaults
let users = [User(username: "user1", email: "user1@xxx.com", password: "******"), User(username: "user2", email: "user2@xxx.com", password: "******")]

var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: teams)
userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "users")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Get data by unarchiving like below

```
let decodedUserDetail  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "users") as! Data
let decodedUsers= NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedUserDetail) as! [Team]
print(decodedUsers)
```

2.You can store multiple values using Array of objects.

```
let userDetails =
[
    "username" : "user1",
    "email": "user1@xxx.com",
    "password" : "******"
]
```

before storing this get existing details

```
  let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  var storedUserDetails = userDefault.objectForKey("userDetails") as?  [[String:AnyObject]]
  storedUserDetails.append(userDetails )

  userDefault.setObject(storedCredentials, forKey: "credentials")
  userDefault.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model

```
Class User: NSObject, NSCoding{
var userName: String
var email_id: String
var password: String

init(userName: String, email_id: String, password: String){
 self.userName = userName
 self.email_id = email_id
 self.password = password
}
required conveniece init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
 let userName = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userName") as? String ?? ""
 let email_id = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email_id") as? String ?? ""
 let password = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "password") as? String ?? ""
 self.init(
   userName=userName,
   email_id=email_id,
   password=password
 )
}

func encode(with coder: NSCoder){
 coder.encode(self.userName, forKet="userName")
 coder.encode(self.email_id, forKet="email_id")
 coder.encode(self.password, forKet="password")
}
}
```

After you can instanciate your model with your data

```
let currentUser = User(userName: userName.text!, email_id: email_id.text!, password: password.text!)
```

Or a list :

```
 let listUsers = [User(userName: "user_1", email_id: "email@abc.com", password: "password")]
```

Now you can store the `currentUser` or `listUsers` with `archivedData`

```
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: currentUser)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "currentUser")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let encodedDataForList = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: listUsers)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "listUsers")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

To get the stored user :

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "currentUser"){
 let _currentUser = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? User)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving user's data, using local db is the most appropriate solution.But if you don't want to go into depth of Core data / Sqlite, use Realm framework.

With Realm you just have to have a user class with dynamic properties & call basic functions like

Initialize RealmDb with

```
let objRealm = try! Realm()
```

Create a user class

```
class UserDataModel: Object {
    dynamic var name:String = ""
    dynamic var ID = ""
     // MARK : Primary Key
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}
```

Add user into DB with write function

```
  let obj = UserDataModel(value: ["name": userName,
                                        "ID": userID])
        try! objRealm.write {
            objRealm.add(obj)
        }
```

Read object from Realm DB

```
return objRealm.objects(UserDataModel.self)
```